# Ruby 2D array comparison

Tags: arrays, ruby

We have a 2D array as follows where A, B etc are the literals [string values]:

```
arr1 = [["A","B"], ["C","D"], ["E","F"], ["G","H"]]
```

now i want to compare this `arr1` with another array and remove the matching elements in the array, the other array is follows:

```
arr2 = [["C"], ["F"]]
```

i want to make sure that if any of the element matches with the element in `arr1`, the corresponding element should be removed from the `arr1` and output should be as follows:

```
output = [["A","B"], ["G","H"]]
```

Comment: You need to define the problem better. Is `[A,B]` allowed because there's no matches in `arr2`? What if `arr2` has `[C,D]` as an element?

Comment: @tadman yes, [A,B] is allowed in the output because there is no match and the format of arr2 will remain same there can not be an element like [C,D] it can be in the form of [[C], [D]]

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Thanks!! A, B are the string literals, I have updated the post..

Comment: You can surround `arr1` in the text (three places) with backticks (`\`arr`\`) to have it appear greyed-out like your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a2 = arr2.flatten
  #=> ["C", "F"] 

arr1.reject { |a| (a & a2).any? } 
  #=> [["A", "B"], ["G", "H"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this

```
arr1.select{|el| ( el & arr2.flatten ).empty? }
```

Comment: ohh sorry, i usually working on rails console and i forget that  method blank? is only for rails